# How to configure Stun/Turn in ejabberd running in kuberbetes environment?

Tags: ejabberd

I'm trying to configure STUN/TURN in ejabberd which is running in Kubernetes environment. While we have to open a range of UDP ports for stun/turn configuration, in kubernetes I can't open a large range of ports in the deployment and service yaml files.
I was thinking if opening range of ports in LB will work without opening in service yaml, but I'm not sure whether it'll work that way.

Please help in configuring stun/turn for ejabberd running in kubernetes.

Comment: At least STUN is probably meant to run outside of any NAT to fulfill  its role of helping systems behind NAT (the N in STUN or TURN). Such role is hampered by being itself subject to NAT. So putting this behind Kubernetes looks weird to me.